# What is the difference between two sentences? What is the wrong part of this sentence.From whom, that I can receive the money is very important

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, clauses

I wanna know the difference between two sentences bellow.

> 1. From whom, **that** I can receive the money is very important.
> 2. From whom I can receive the money is very important.

And if you make the sentences, what do you prefer and what is the reason why you chose the sentence?

I will wait for you kind answer. Help me, please

Comment: Please use want to and not wanna. Wanna is texting style or very informal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Natural sounding sentences in English usually do not begin with prepositional phrases like *from whom, * except maybe in a question, and usually a formal question.

- **From whom** do you receive money, Mr. Kim?
- Is it important for you to know whom you receive it from?
- **Whom**, in fact, do you receive it from?

Right, **so the above is formal.** People **actually say who here** and it's fine in spoken English:

Who, in fact, do you receive it from?

Answer: **Who** I receive money from is important to me. OR   **Whom** I receive money from is important.

Generally, therefore, we would start the sentence with who or whom and not *from whom* in a declarative sentence (not a question).

It is true that the verb receive takes **from** but it is usually placed at the end and separately from the who or whom.

There is no need for a *that*. *That* introduces a relative clause:

- The money **that I receive** from my family is always in cash.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose one, it would be the second. The first sounds ungrammatical as *whom* and *that* seem to be vying for the same role in the sentence. As a general comment, many people tend to avoid *whom* these days. It's certainly not wrong to use it but it trips up some, and dwindling usage means it can sound archaic in normal everyday, especially spoken, English. But it's still very common in formal and legalistic prose. In your example it is correctly used and sounds fine to me.

Comment: You use whom when you need it. It is not needed here really.